# Nodemailer transporter seems to break when used a script function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

i came here with a nodemailer situation, i'm building a contact form and to avoid php i was trying to use nodemailer on js however i found a problem.

When i use nodemailer on a simples mailer.js and use "node mailer.js" it works:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'person',
  to: 'email',
  subject: 'Teste nodemailer',
  text: `Teste`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

but when i try to insert it on the script that validades the form:

```
async function sendIT(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var msg= document.getElementById('msg').value;

    var error = false;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById('nameError').classList.add('error');
        error = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('nameError').classList.remove('error');
    }
    if(msg == ""){
        document.getElementById('msgError').classList.add('error');
        error = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('msgError').classList.remove('error');
    }
    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(email))){
        document.getElementById('emailError').classList.add('error');
        error = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('emailError').classList.remove('error');
    }

    if(!error){
          var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
              user: 'email',
              pass: 'passwor'
            }
        });
          var mailOptions = {
            from: 'person',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Test nodemailer',
            text: 'The ' +name+ ' sent the following message:\n\n\n' + msg
          };
          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
                alert('e-mail failed')
              console.log(error);
            } else {
                alert('E-mail sent');
              console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
          });
    }
}
```

And the error seems to be on the 'transporter' because it is when i create the transporter or when i try to use it to send an e-mail that the scripts breaks.

Does anyone know why this happens? Thank you for the time spent reading and responding to this question

Edit.:
The line

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

at the top of the script file gives an error on the browser `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, an error that it should not happen since i'm using nodejs.

Comment: what do you mean by "it breaks"? Do you get any errors? Are you should your if-statement `if(!error)` is executing, what do you see if you `console.log(error)` above your if-statement?

Comment: with "it breaks" i mean that when the script reaches the transporter creation it just won't continue. The if statement works and the `console.log(error)` returns `false` as it should

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your script seems to be hanging, and it isn't producing any errors in the console?

Comment: No, but i just debugging using the browser console itself and half the times it responds with `cannot read property 'createTransport' of undefined`. which makes me think that the script cannot access the nodemailer however the code is the same and i can't understand why it does it

Comment: Are you using `var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');` at the top of your file?

Comment: yes i am, and i also have `body-parser` on `app.js`

Comment: You would like to use `nodemailer` in `nodejs` and not in the browser. So send HTTP request with the form data to your `nodejs` server and then send the email from there